# How can you make "to be" explicit and simple in this future conditional sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subjunctive-mood, irregular

I can say "Jerry's been a bad pussycat this morning" or "Hey, Jerry, you be a good pussycat now" or "Jerry's been active all morning so he's being a good pussycat now". All these involve the use of the verb *be*.

Now if I said "if Jerry bes a bad pussycat, put him in the laundry," I'll sound ungrammatical. How else can you say this without being specific about the verb? I understand the future tense of **to be** is **is** but then it sounds like present tense rather than future tense.

I don't want to say "if Jerry behaves badly" because it's too complex. And I don't want to say "if Jerry is bad" because that implies current state rather than future state.

Should it be "if Jerry would be bad..." or "if Jerry should be bad" perhaps?

Comment: Hi Lisa, and welcome to EL&U! Is it possible for you to take out some of the peeving in your question, so that it fits better with our [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)? It will help other users answer your question.

Comment: I'm not sure how to change it. I'm more than happy for you to edit it though.

Comment: I just changed a little formatting--your first line was the one I was referring to. So, to get a better idea about your question, you're asking for a future tense version of "If Jerry is bad, then put him in the laundry"?

Comment: Lisa, I made a few edits as well. You can roll them back if you object.

Comment: How about *If Jerry gets bad…* or *If Jerry becomes bad…* or *If Jerry does not stay good…*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [subjunctive mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive#English) here. In order to form the future subjunctive mood for *to be* in clauses in which there is doubt, you would use *if I/he/she/it, etc. were to be* as follows:

> Were Jerry to be bad, put him in the laundry.
>
> If Jerry were to be bad, put him in the laundry.

or you could say:

> Should Jerry be bad, put him in the laundry.

The last choice sounds best to my ear.

The subjunctive mood is to be used [when talking about events that somebody imagines.](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-subjunctive.htm)

Comment: Note that *if Jerry be's bad* (or *bees bad*) is grammatical in some dialects of English, or for some speakers. Some examples are discussed in [this paper on agentive and habitual be](https://files.nyu.edu/cc116/public/agentive_be%28final%29.pdf) (PDF). If a particular dialect feature is or isn't grammatical for you, it doesn't mean we can infer anything about your intelligence :)

Comment: Good comment.  I'd say the subjunctive mood is largely unused in American English at least. +1

Comment: Marking as answer because I like it the best. Hellion's answer quite valid too. All three of these sound nice to my ear. Thank you for pointing out this is the subjunctive mood.

Answer (score 2):

While the subjunctive that Spare Oom gives may be grammatically correct, it will still sound very strange to most people (though his third choice is definitely the least uncommon of them).  What I would recommend as "everyday English" is:

> If Jerry starts being bad, put him in the laundry.

P.s.  The future tense of "to be" is not "is", it's "will be", as in `He was bad, he is bad, he will be bad.`

Comment: That "everyday English" suggestion is fine, but use of the present tense ("is") is also fine in a conditional sentence in everyday English.  Using another verb, an example: _If he crys, try rocking him_.  Similarly, _if Jerry is bad, put him in the laundry_ would be widely acceptable.

Comment: How do you explain "he has been bad", "he's being bad" and "he is going to be bad". Are these not past, present and future as well? How can you know something *will* happen if it's in the future. It might not??